# Keep only 'by' variables when collapsing data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a very large data.table:

```
DT <- data.table(a=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),b=c(1,1,2,2),c=1:12)
```

And I need to collapse it `by` several variables, e.g. list(a,b).  Easy:

```
DT[,sum(c),by=list(a,b)]

   a b V1
1: 1 1  3
2: 1 2  7
3: 2 1 11
4: 2 2 15
5: 3 1 19
6: 3 2 23
```

However, I don't want to take any operation on `c`, I just want to drop it:

```
DT[,,by=list(a,b)]       # includes a,b,c, thus does not collapse
DT[,list(),by=list(a,b)] # zero rows
DT[,a,by=list(a,b)]      # what I want but adds extraneous column a after 'by' columns
```

How can I specify `X` below to get the indicated result?

```
DT[,X,by=list(a,b)]

   a b
1: 1 1
2: 1 2
3: 2 1
4: 2 2
5: 3 1
6: 3 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unique.data.table` has a `by` argument, you could then subset result to get the columns you want.

eg

```
unique(DT, by = c('a', 'b'))[, c('a','b')]
```

Comment: Accepted, but I used: `DT[,b,by=list(a,b)][,b := NULL]` instead.  In practice, my `by` list is quite long (5-6 variables), and even longer quoted.  But it's helpful to know there's not an elegant way to do this (`unique` here still includes column `c`, which you have excluded with a subquery as I also have).  I use column `b` since the subquery removes the *first* column `b`, so duplicating anything but the last column will cause my column ordering to change.